# How do I connect these two vertices by extending them along its edge util they reach each other?

Tags: vertices

How do I connect these two vertices by extending them along its edge util they reach each other?

Since the left edge is parallel with the Y axis, it is easy to move the vertex down the Y axis, but how do I move the vertex of the bottom edge since it is not parallel with the X axis?

[image]

Comment: Enable addon tinyCad, there should be Auto option in the right click menu

Comment: @MrZak that did it! thank you very much! Make your comment an answer and I will mark it as the solution, if you want!

Comment: You're welcome to post it instead with sharing screenshots of how you did that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: grilled by Mr Zak  ;)

You can extend the 2 edges so that they overlap: slide <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> and <kbd>C</kbd> to extend. Then enable the *TinyCAD* addon, select all and right click > *TinyCAD > XALL Intersect*, it will create a vertex at the intersection. Remove the rest.

[image]

Or, as mentionned by the Great Robin Betts, don't slide, just select all and choose *VTX Auto*, it will intersect automatically, you'll just have to dissolve the remaining vertices with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: Grilling you some more ... you have the option of using  VTX AUTO, eliminating the need to slide. Well ..OK, you have to dissolve some verts instead, much of a muchness.

Comment: wow I didn't know that, I'm going to edit my answer